# wp7 list Peel animation

Tags: windows-phone-7, animation

I am using List Peel animation as described [here](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/03/). Its working as expected but now I want to add the similar effect on onItemSelectionChanged event of the list box. The only difference is that this time, I want the selected item to leave the page at the very last. How can that be achieved?

Regards

Comment: Avoid using selection changed to trigger a navigation as it is very easy to accidentally select an item when performing a gesture-such as swiping to navigate through a list.

Comment: What do you use instead @Matt? (doesn't the same problem occur for Tap?)

Comment: @Stuart No. A tap is a separate, discrete gesture (when compared with swipe). I use Tap on the individual items.

Comment: It's not my suggestion - I still don't think using Tap makes any difference

Answer (score 1):

I think that Clarity's turnstile with feather transition might be what you are looking for:

http://blogs.claritycon.com/blog/2010/10/13/wp7-page-transitions-sample/

I can't quite remember how it works... but I remember it did act on individual elements - it tried to work like the start menu.

Comment: I saw it too... but I don't want to use it because I am using Toolkit in all other screens (I have list view in only one of my screens and for this, I don't want to use any other extra library). Also Claritycon somehow interfere with toolkit (some properties in the app.xaml.cs). So I was thinking if I can use directly toolkit for this. Still thanks for your answer